# Instalar composer en ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, composer, ubuntu-server

Que tal se me presento un problema requiero instalar composer desde el archivo composer.json, en ubuntu pero solo en un proyecto no global, siendo mas claros en windows se puede instalar de la sgte manera:

```
instalar composer windows
primero copiar el archivo de composer.json en la carpeta  a instalar
luego por cmd entrar a la carpeta a instalar composer
y ejecutar los comandos 
composer install
```

Una ves instalado tengo los archivos `composer.json`,  `composer.lock` y la carpeta de vendor, que es de donde necesito sacar los recursos

Mi pregunta es que si en ubuntu se puede hacer lo mismo por que windows puedo hacerlo solo en le proyecto que trabajare. Si alguien supuiera algunos pasos me vendria bien una ayuda vi como hacerlo en ubuntu pero lo instala global. Gracias

Comment: No te ha servido la propia documentación de composer para hacer una instalación local ? https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#locally, si no te ha servido cual es el problema que has encontrado al hacerlo?